# Hacer UPDATE con datos de un ARRAY en MySQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

Me ocupa lo siguiente: poseo una 1 tabla de nombre `recargar` en donde tengo datos varios (filas). Dichos datos contenidos poseen lógicamente varios campos(columnas), uno de esos campos me relaciona los datos con la tabla `pedidos` por medio de la columna `pedidos.id` y otro campo, en donde deseo colocar un numero de confirmación.

El numero de confirmación lo obtengo mediante un input, en el input agregare una lista de códigos de confirmación que los obtendré por otra vía desde un spreadsheets, todos estos datos serán copiados y pegados en el input al hacerlo estos ya estarán separados por uno o 2 espacios.

Un ejemplo de los datos que serán pegados en mi input es: `11111 22222 33333 44444`. De esta manera serán ingresado los datos en el input, normalmente separados por un espacio pero aveces pueden tener espacio doble, por ello primero debo primero sustituir si existe un espacio doble en un espacio simple y luego mediante un explode los separo en la cantidad de números de confirmación sean ingresados desde el input. ejemplo en mi ejemplo serán 4 códigos que deseo asignar a 4 filas que ya existen en mi tabla `recargar`.

```
function confirmaciones(){
    global $db;
    $id_pedido = $_REQUEST['id_pedido'];
    $confirmacion = $_REQUEST['confirmacion'];

    $lote_confirmacion = str_replace("  ", " ", $confirmacion);

    $codigo = explode(' ', $lote_confirmacion);

   var_dump($codigo);

 for ($y=0; $y<count($codigo);  $y++) {
     //echo $codigo[$y].'<br/>';
     $sql = "UPDATE recargar SET confirmacion = '$codigo[$y]', status = 3 WHERE relacion = $id_pedido";

     if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
         $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = "Exito $codigo[$y].<br>";
       } else {
         $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Algo ha ocurrido, intente efectuar su declaracion nuevamente.';

         }

     }

    //$_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = ;



}
```

El resultado si le hago un `var_dump($codigo);` es el siguiente:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(5) "11111" 
[1]=> string(5) "22222" 
[2]=> string(5) "33333" 
[3]=> string(5) "44444" }
```

El query que se ejecuta donde tengo el input para recuperar los datos que no tienen asignado confirmación lo obtengo con las siguientes lineas:

```
     $query2 = "SELECT * 
FROM recargar 
WHERE id_pedido = '$rowid'
AND confirmacion IS NULL
ORDER BY id ASC";
```

De acá se me ha ocurrido recuperar un arreglo dentro del while y ejecutando fuera del arreglo la siguiente linea `$aid[]=$id; var_dump($aid);` dando como resultado Ejemplo:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(1) "1" 
[1]=> string(1) "2" 
[2]=> string(1) "7" 
[3]=> string(1) "9" }
```

Pero no se como pasar este arreglo mediante un input a la function `confirmaciones()`, he intentado creando una variable `$vid = unserialize($aid)` pero me da error imagino que no es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

**LO QUE REQUIERO:**

Requiero que al agregar una cantidad de textos separados con espacios estos sean actualizados a un grupo de datos que ya están en el mismo orden.

Tampoco se como debo ejecutar la sentencia SQL en mi function `confirmaciones()` para que se haga en mi base de datos la actualización del campo confirmación de un dato null a los obtenidos con la function `confirmaciones()` el orden en que son ingresados los datos en el input es el mismo orden que debe tener en la tabla recargar ordenados por su id de forma ASC, o en su defecto el orden en que son recuperados en el arreglo `$aid[]=$id` que como dije antes no se como pasarlos vía input a mi function `confirmaciones()`.

En mi tabla `recargar` tengo por ejemplo los siguientes datos:

```
id   dato1   dato2   id_pedido   confirmacion
1    jkjk    jkjkj   4           NULL
2    kjfk    lklkk   4           NULL
7    kljkf   ñlñll   4           NULL
9    lklk    lklkl   4           NULL
```

Los datos que ingreso en mi input seria algo como: `aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccccc ddddddddd` y lo que quisiera hacer es un update que quede así:

```
id   dato1   dato2   id_pedido   confirmacion
1    jkjk    jkjkj   4           aaaaaaaaa
2    kjfk    lklkk   4           bbbbbbbbb
7    kljkf   ñlñll   4           ccccccccc
9    lklk    lklkl   4           ddddddddd
```

Lógicamente en esta tabla hay mucho mas datos pero solo quiero que se actualicen los que el `id_pedido` sea igual al procesado en mi function `confirmaciones()` o que los id sean los recuperados en mi `query2`.

Tal cual como tengo actualmente mi function `confirmaciones()` solo actualiza con el ultimo dato de mi input es decir, queda algo como lo siguiente:

```
id   dato1   dato2   id_pedido   confirmacion
1    jkjk    jkjkj   4           ddddddddd
2    kjfk    lklkk   4           ddddddddd
7    kljkf   ñlñll   4           ddddddddd
9    lklk    lklkl   4           ddddddddd
```

En vez de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
id   dato1   dato2   id_pedido   confirmacion
1    jkjk    jkjkj   4           aaaaaaaaa
2    kjfk    lklkk   4           bbbbbbbbb
7    kljkf   ñlñll   4           ccccccccc
9    lklk    lklkl   4           ddddddddd
```

**Replanteando mi consulta**

Segun la sugerencia indicada y aclarado mejor el panorama replanteo la busqueda de mi solucion he implementado mi function de la siguiente manera:

```
   function confirmaciones(){
    global $db;
    $mysqli = "";
    $id_pedido = $_REQUEST['id_pedido'];
    $confirmacion = $_REQUEST['confirmacion'];
    $lote_confirmacion = str_replace("  ", " ", $confirmacion);

    $allValues = explode(' ', $lote_confirmacion);

    $allIDs=[];

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM recargar WHERE relacion = '$id_pedido' ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
    $row2 =  mysqli_num_rows($result2);

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
    {
        $id = $row2['id'] ;
        $allIDs[]=$id;
}

//var_dump($allIDs);

//var_dump($allValues);

$allParams=array_combine($allIDs,$allValues);

var_dump($allParams);

if($allParams){
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    $sql="UPDATE recargar SET confirmacion = ?, status = 3 WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $value,$id);
    $status=TRUE;
    foreach ($allParams as $id=>$value) {
        $stmt->execute() ? null : $msg =$stmt->error;
    }

    if(!$msg){
        $mysqli->commit();
        $msg= "Todo ok";
    }else{
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
    $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
} else {
    $msg="Error, no se pueden combinar los valores, por favor revísalos";
}
$mysqli->close();
echo $msg;



}
```

Rectifico ahora mi problema:

1. Desde mi formulario envio los datos de donde se recuperaran la variable `$allValues` eso funciona perfecto
2. En mi function `confirmaciones()` hago un `select` donde recupero los id en la variable `$allIDs` esto tambien funciona perfecto y estos id son unicos no se repiten ya que son KEY AUTOINCREMENT.
3. Ahora en la query `$sql` en la linea  `WHERE relacion = ?` la cambie a `WHERE id = ?` ya que la columna id es la que contiene las id unicas de mis datos de la tabla `recargar` con la columna `relacion` es identificar cuales solo coinciden con la variable `$id_pedido` pero ya eso lo hace mi consulta `query2`
4. El resultado de `var_dump($allParams);` es perfectamente el esperado en la sugerencia indicada, en un ejemplo de 8 datos a ser actualizados el resultado var_dump es:

   `array(8) { 
       [2]=> string(3) "111" 
       [12]=> string(3) "222" 
       [14]=> string(3) "333" 
       [16]=> string(3) "444" 
       [17]=> string(3) "555" 
       [18]=> string(3) "666" 
       [19]=> string(3) "777" 
       [20]=> string(3) "888" }`

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
    Fatal error: 
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function autocommit()
 on string in $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
```

Comment: Buenas, no me queda claro lo que intentas hacer, de echo tampoco entiendo muy bien la funcionalidad del for, porque count($codigo) normalmente tiene el valor 1 ¿no? ¿Lo que quieres es cambiarle el valor de "confirmacion" a una sola fila de la tabla o a todas las que tengan null al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Como menciona Juanant, no se entiende muy bien que quieres hacer. Según mi interpretación; tienes un input donde ingresas valores separados por (espacio), quieres que cuando el formulario sea enviado se ejecute una función *confirmacion()* y esta hace un update sobre el campo de una tabla. Deseas saber como actualizar ese campo con todos esos valores que obtuviste en el input al mismo tiempo.

Comment: De ser ese el caso, te recomiendo que prepares un arreglo donde obtengas todos los valores de la tabla a la que quieres hacer el update. Luego coges los valors obtenidos en el input y haces una comparacion: es decir UPDATE tabla SET columna = valor WHERE valor_id = valor_row. Esa sentencia la metes dentro de un bucle. Hará una actualizacion cada vez que encuentre un valor que coincida. Si cuentra coincidencia actualiza el campo, sino, no. Espero que eso te sirva, o te acerque a tu solución

Comment: Tienes que recorrer con un for o un while las distintas filas que te llegan de tu select from, dentro del for que recorre los valores separados por espacios con el explode. Dentro de ese bucle debes recoger en una variable el valor de `id` para cada fila y hacer un `UPDATE recargar SET confirmacion = $codigo[y] where id = $idFila` para que se actualice el campo confirmacion comparando por id, que es un valor único que no se repite. El UPDATE que te he puesto es de ejemplo, puede que necesites poner alguna que otra comilla en alguna parte o concatenar.

Comment: Saludos, @JoelMuñozMoran gracias por sus comentarios, he editado mi consulta y he tratado de explicar de manera mas detallada lo que deseo hacer

Comment: Muestra un `var_dump` de las variables, creo que se verá más claro y podremos sugerirte algo mucho mejor y más seguro.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano el var_dump ingresando datos 1111 22222 33333 44444 es el siguiente: `array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "1111" [1]=> string(5) "22222" [2]=> string(5) "33333" [3]=> string(5) "44444" }`

Comment: He intentado lo siguiente sin exito  ` for ($y=0; $y<count($codigo);  $y++) {
        //echo $codigo[$y].'<br/>';
        $sql = "UPDATE recargar SET confirmacion = '$codigo[$y]', status = 3 WHERE relacion = $id_pedido";

        if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
            $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = "Exito $codigo[$y].<br>";
          } else {
            $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Algo ha ocurrido, intente efectuar su declaracion nuevamente.';
          
            }
        
        }`

Comment: El codigo anterior me da error ya que me ingresa solo el ultimo dato ingresado ejemplo ingresando: 1111 22222 3333 4444 el update lo hace solo con 4444

Comment: Te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua, pues esto se resuelve muy fácil y además con seguridad, aplicando consultas preparadas. Pero no llego a tener todavía una visión de los datos, no entiendo a qué exactamente pertenece el `var_dump` que muestras en tu comentario. Por favor edita la pregunta y pon las cosas claramente, mostrando los var_dump de la información que estás manejando. En el código haces unas manipulaciones extrañas con los datos que creo que no son necesarias y no hacen más que confundir. Explica qué datos manejas y olvídate querer forzar una solución con esa lógica.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano ok, ya he editado mi consulta, he tratado de explicar que he intentado hacer y cual es la salida que me esta dando mi codigo.

Comment: Bueno ahora se entiende mejor. Solamente una última cosa: ¿los datos de la `query2` vienen junto con el array de valores o los obtienes antes del `UPDATE`? ¿En qué variable se encuentran esos datos?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano ese query2 lo ejecuto antes de mis input de hecho alli puedo tambien recuperar las id de cada dato de la tabla recarga a las cuales quiero se vean actualizadas he recuperado un arreglo mediante la siguiente forma `$aid[]=$id;
var_dump($aid);` dando como resultado Ejemplo: `array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(2) "12" [2]=> string(2) "14" [3]=> string(2) "16" }` pero tampoco se como pasarla via input ese arreglo creo que de esa manera se puede hacer la sentencia de mejor forma..!! logicamente sigo leyendo pero no logro terminar de comprender como hacerlo funcionar..!

Comment: @A.Cedano He replanteado mi pregunta y he agregado la posibilidad de pasar los id de las filas a ser editadas mediante un arreglo, pero este arreglo debo pasarlos via input a mi function `confirmaciones()` y eso tampoco se como hacerlo de forma correcta..! pero imagino que de esa manera seria mucho mas seguro editar solo las filas de las id que son recuperadas en la `query2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José te propongo una solución basada en consultas preparadas (para neutralizar riesgos de *Inyección SQL*). Además usamos transacciones para asegurar de que se harán todos los cambios o ninguno, informando de la causa en caso de que algún cambio no se haga (por ejemplo se se produce una clave duplicada o algo así).

**Dejo a tu cuidado** que crees dos arrays válidos: uno con los ids y otro con los valores a actualizar. Esos arrays los vamos a combinar en uno solo. Si desde el origen los puedes traer combinados mucho mejor.

Aquí usaré `array_combine`, asumiendo que en ningún momento los ids se repetirán. Si eso llegara a ocurrir, habría que usar otra técnica. La cuestión es que el array final con el que va a trabajar el código debe quedar así:

```
Array
(
    [1] => aaa
    [2] => bbb
    [7] => ccc
    [9] => ddd
)
```

A la izquierda los ids, a la derecha los valores. En el código esa variable se llama `$allParams`.

Ahí vamos:

```
$allIDs=array(1,2,7, 9);
$allValues=array("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd");
$allParams=array_combine($allIDs,$allValues);
if($allParams){
    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
    $sql="UPDATE recargar SET confirmacion = ?, status = 3 WHERE relacion = ?";
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $value,$id);
    $status=TRUE;
    foreach ($allParams as $id=>$value) {
        $stmt->execute() ? null : $msg =$stmt->error;
    }

    if(!$msg){
        $mysqli->commit();
        $msg= "Todo ok";
    }else{
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
    $mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
} else {
    $msg="Error, no se pueden combinar los valores, por favor revísalos";
}
$mysqli->close();
echo $msg;
```

Con esto debería funcionar. Si no entiendes algo, lo dices en un comentario a la respuesta.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Saludos, si creo comprender la propuesta pero no se como pasar de mi pag donde tengo el input el array de las id que voy a modificar..! de hecho he creado otra consulta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238538/recuperar-un-arreglo-y-pasarlo-via-input a ver si de pronto como me estas indicando puedo solucionar mi interrogante..!

Comment: Listo, tenia un error en la variable `$mysqli` que en mi codigo es `$db` y me daba error lógicamente porque la variable de conexión a la base de datos no estaba definida, pero funciona perfecto, ahora voy a personalizar.. de verdad que muchas gracias..!

Comment: En la linea  `foreach ($allParams as $id=>$value) {
        $stmt->execute() ? null : $msg =$stmt->error;
    }` tengo una variable `$msg` no definida si la declaro `$msg="";` al principio de mi codigo no altera el funcionamiento..?

Comment: Sí lo altera. Es una estrategia que uso ahí para saber si ocurre algún error dentro del bucle. Fíjate en el `if` que hay basado en esa variable. Si hasta ahí es nula significa que no hubo errores ejecutando la consulta y a partir de ahí la variable tomará otro valor si es nula. Revisa la lógica y verás.