# Recuperar un arreglo y pasarlo via input

Tags: php, array, entrada, while

Poseo el siguiente codigo:

```
    $aid=[];
    $i = 1;
              while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
    {
        $id = $row2['id'] ;
    $tipo = $row2['tipo'] ;
    $numero = $row2['nro'] ;
    $aid[]=$id;
    }
```

Si hago el `var_dump($aid);` obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
array(8) { 
[0]=> string(1) "2" 
[1]=> string(2) "12" 
[2]=> string(2) "14" 
[3]=> string(2) "16" 
[4]=> string(2) "17" 
[5]=> string(2) "18" 
[6]=> string(2) "19" 
[7]=> string(2) "20" }
```

En la misma pag poseo el siguiente codigo input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="'.$tipo.'">
<input type="hidden" name="id_recarga" value="'.$aid.'">
```

Y en la function que recibe dichos datos poseo lo siguiente:

```
$tipo = $_REQUEST['tipo'];
$aid = $_REQUEST['id_recarga'];
```

Mi consulta es como puedo pasar de manera correcta el arreglo de mi variable `$aid` a mi function que recibe los datos de los input.

Comment: Leí esta pregunta, pero no entendí muy bien. En otra pregunta parecía que querías recuperar algunos id con un `SELECT` para usarlos criterios en un `UPDATE`
 pero esta pregunta me parece otra cosa  ¿? Tengo la intuición de que esto es fácil de resolver, pero que has tomado un camino largo. Si explicas mejor aquí lo que quieres te podemos echar un cable. ¿El array de 8 elementos que muestras qué es en sí y de dónde viene?

Comment: Es del mismo problema, logico aca copie directo de mi codigo, estos datos los obtengo de mi `query2` del problema que usted me ha intentado ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237820/hacer-update-con-datos-de-un-array-en-mysql-desde-php/238569#238569 creo que si logri pasar estas id a mi function  `confirmaciones()` podre aplicar la solucion que me sugieres..!

Comment: En el ejemplo anterior estaba trabajando con 4 id y logicamente con 4 datos de confirmacion, en este caso estoy tratando de pasar 8 id que es lo que esta recuperando mi `SELECT` para pasarlos en conjunto con mi input de confirmacion que es el que posee los datos `aaa bbb ccc ddd` o `111 2222 333 444` para el caso de agregar 4 codigos de confirmacion a 4 id diferentes..!

Comment: Pero una cosa, aquí estamos antes de lanzar el código de servidor para hacer el update. Lo que me pregunto es, ¿aquí necesitas esos datos para otra cosa o sólo los necesitas para hacer el update? Porque de ser así, es mejor pasar esa consulta del otro lado, lanzándola antes de hacer el update. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Antes de lanzar el codigo `UPDATE` lo uso para mostrar a cuales datos se efectuara el update, pero creo que perfectamente puedo lanzar un `SELECT` antes del `UPDATE` con la finalidad de obtener los id dejame intentar modificar el codigo a ver que tal..!!!