# Ejecutar muchas sentencias de MYSQL en una sola instrucción

Tags: mysql

Estoy enviando al servidor instrucciones simples de MYSQL para borrar registros de uno por uno, lo que implica mucho tiempo ya que envío datos por internet de instrucción por instrucción, no es óptimo ya que creo que podría enviar todas las sentencias en un solo comando de instrucciones masivas, pero al crear el "conjunto de instrucciones" obtengo un error de sintaxis que no se cual es, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=mysql_num_rows($Tsqlusuarios)-1;$i++)
{
    $RTsqlusuarios=mysql_fetch_assoc($Tsqlusuarios);
    $sql=$sql."delete from UsuariosMedidas where idUsuario=".$RTsqlusuarios['IDUsuariosPrendas'].";";


} mysql_query($sql): //Esto me marca error
```

El error es que supuestamente hay error en la sintaxis, no entiendo por que si yo imprimo la variable $sql y la copio y la meto a un cliente de SQL para que se ejecute lo hace correctamente sin fallas, pero si lo mando ejecutar en este programa de la forma como dice el código marca error.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como debo armar el paquete de instrucciones?

Comment: Captura el error y dinos cual es: `if ( mysql_query($sql) ) { echo "Todo OK"; } else { echo "ERROR: ". mysql_error($con); }`  debes cambiar  `$con` por tu variable de conexión. Ahora mismo no recuerdo si con `mysql_` puedes mandar varias consultas concatenadas... Por otra parte, la extensión `mysql_` quedó obsoleta hace años, deberías pasar a `mysqli` y para este tipo de cosas: 1. usar consultas preparadas; 2. usar transacciones. Esas dos cosas optimizan el tratamiento de datos masivos y aportan seguridad al código.

Comment: Ya lo verifiqué, `mysql_query` no admite consultas múltiples. [Está dicho claramente en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php): *`mysql_query()` envía una única consulta (no hay soporte para múltiples consultas) a la base de datos actualmente activa en el servidor asociado con el identificador de enlace especificado por link_identifier.*

Comment: El error no es de conexión, el error lo marca al tratar de ejecutar el paquete de comandos como si las instrucciones estuvieran mal hechas.

Comment: Uchales y entonces que se hace?? Enviar instrucción de una por una resulta en una ejecución de respuesta demasiado tardada!!

Comment: Como te dije antes, para estos casos: 1. Usar consultas preparadas (el plan de ejecución se traza una sola vez, lo cual optimiza bastante, y no sólo, sino que evitas ataques de hackers); 2. Usar transacciones (también optimiza y sobre todo reviertes todo si algo falla, evitando inconsistencias y la locura de saber qué se borró y que no). Pero para todo ello deberás migrar a la API `mysqli`. No lo veas demasiado grande, deberás hacerlo tarde o temprano y es muy fácil. La extensión que estás usando es obsoleta e insegura, aparte de tener limitaciones como no admitir multi query.

Comment: Una transaccion es una instruccion en MYSQL que se puede revertir si falla?

Comment: ¿Cuantos registros esta intentado eliminar? Si no son demasiados, otra opción es hacer un solo `DELETE` utilizando [`el operador IN ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in). Sino, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la consulta de trae los datos? se podría hacer un `DELETE` usando la misma condición que utilizas para obtener los datos

Comment: Una transacción es mucho más que una instrucción SQL. Es una herramienta que poseen las bases de datos para usarla en el tratamiento de datos masivos. Por decirlo de alguna forma, con transacciones se intenta borrar cada dato, si algún error ocurre, reviertes ese intento, si no hay errores lo confirmas y el borrado se realiza. Imagina que tienes que borrar 1,000 filas y en un punto del borrado algo falla, ¿cómo sabrás cuáles filas se borran y cuáles no?

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo de transacciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/238569/29967). Para hacerlo así: 1. Tienes que pasar a `mysqli`; 2. Tienes que asegurarte que la tabla está en `InnoDB`. El ejemplo usa además consultas preparadas. Es un `UPDATE`, pero para un  `DELETE` es un procedimiento parecido.

Comment: los registros a eliminar pueden ser muchos, cientos, mandar una instrucción con mysql_query con una sentencia "delete" en un for hace que mi programa tarde muchos minutos en arrojar el resultado y eso no esta bonito y ya me regañaron en el trabajo, tengo que buscar una forma de mandar TODO el paquete de instrucciones en una sola instrucción, para tratar de agilizar el tiempo de respuesta. El operador IN no se si sea buena solución, ahora no solo se trata de borrar, tambien tengo que INSERTAR muchos registros y eso también toma tiempo por estarlo haciendo de uno por uno con mysql_query,

Comment: En el caso de las transacciones puedo revertir en caso de que exista un error al borrar, ¿Pero que clase de errores? Es muy raro que el servidor falle por que se fué la luz eléctrica, ¿Podría ser por un error de que una de las instrucciones tenía un error de sintaxis?